# Download large files through S3 java sdk 2 without writing to server

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to download large files through AWS without saving it to server and so far nothing I have tried has worked.

Here is the code to fetch from AWS.

```
public ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> downloadFile(String key){


     return s3client.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(key).build(),ResponseTransformer.toInputStream());

}
```

And here is the spring boot controller that is trying to send this response stream back.

```
   @RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadOld(@RequestParam String key, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> responseStream = this.amazonClient.downloadFile(key);
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(responseStream);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + key.substring(key.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + "\"");
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(responseStream.response().contentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(responseStream.response().contentType()))
                .body(resource);
    }
```

I have partial sucess this controller, the axios response.data does have a response. And text files do download correctly , However when the content type is anything other than plain text ( eg application/pdf etc ) , the size of the downloaded file is 1.5 times the original file size. And needless to saw it is corrupted. ( pdf / zip / png ) nothing would open in my app ( cordova app ).

Then I tried sending a `StreamingResponseBody`. Here are two code samples I tried , With both of them this time the axios response is empty.

```
@Async
    @RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> download(@RequestParam String key, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> responseStream = this.amazonClient.downloadFile(key);
        final StreamingResponseBody out = (os) -> {
            readAndWrite(responseStream, os);
        };
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + key.substring(key.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + "\"");
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        return (new ResponseEntity<>(out, headers, HttpStatus.OK));
    }
```

Next tried sending the response without header.

```
@Async
    @RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = GET)
    public StreamingResponseBody download(@RequestParam String key, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> responseStream = this.amazonClient.downloadFile(key);
        return (os) -> {
            readAndWrite(responseStream, os);
        };

    }
```

Straighforward readAndWrite callback implementation.

```
private void readAndWrite(final InputStream is, OutputStream os)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = is.read(data)) > 0) {
            os.write(data, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
    }
```

You can only imagine the headaches I am going through here.

I also tried the newer sdk in-build async approach , which again did not work. Here is the client call.

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse>> downloadAsync(String key){


    return s3AsyncClient.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(key).build(), AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes());

}
```

( Couldn't find on example on Amazon AWS site on how return a stream. They have one example where they used a ResponseTransformer to to save to local file, that doesn't help me).

Corresponding controller for above AsyncResponse.

```
 @Async
    @RequestMapping(path = "/downloadAync", method = GET)
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse>> downloadAsync(@RequestParam String key, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        return this.amazonClient.downloadAsync(key);

    }
```

Comment: You can generate Presigned URL for specific bucket and give this URL back to client. Then client can use this URL for downloading/uploading data directly from/to bucket. Is it not possible in your case?

Comment: Thats a good idea. The above code now works good. The issue in my case was I need to include `responseType: blob` in my axios request.  Now I am able to download and open smaller files. However when the file size is large, an out-of-memory exception is occuring because axios waits for the entire large file download until the stream is closed. I will try and use fetch in place of axios , and if that doesnt work will use presigned url.